# How do you run a Js file on any site?

Tags: javascript, html, automation

I want to automate something on a website that I don't own. It has to fill out a form automatically and do some clicking actions. Will I be able to do this with JS? Because I don't understand how you can run a .js file on a site without the html tag  inside the html code. I can use the console on the site but I want it to look good and clean for users.

Thanks in advance

edit:
So it should look something like this:

1. An user should be able to select an item in an UI
2. Then it will automatically search the item on the website.
3. It will select the item in the right colour and size and add it to the basket.
4. Then it will checkout (fill in the form and pay).

Comment: You can use a *userscript* browser extension like Tampermonkey

Comment: But then each user should install the extension to run the .js file?

Comment: There may be other ways to accomplish what you need depending on what it is but the only way to run js on site you don't control is using a browser extension

Comment: You could make a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to automate actions?
Maybe selenium will work better.
Selenium has the capability of do those task.. like fill forms, click buttons, hover on elements and more.

[Selenium python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction)

Comment: Yes, a user should be able to click on something in an UI and it should start doing automated actions on a specific site. So I should write it in Python so I can use selenium?

Comment: No, sorry. Selenium does not work like that.
It will open new instance of your browser and start doing something that you previously programmed before.
Here an example: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aVI94vIEnw

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very **simple extension**:

You will need two files:

```js
yourCode.js // Here goes your code
manifest.json // Here you target the page
```

Here is what you should put in `manifest.json`:

```json
{

  "manifest_version": 2,         // Mandatory
  "name": "Auto-submit form",    // Mandatory
  "version": "1.0",              // Mandatory



  "content_scripts": [      // This key injects your js file into any target website.
    {
      "matches": ["your target url"], // Pattern: "*://*/*"
      "js": ["yourCode.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

And your code resides in `yourCode.js`:

```js
//Here Goes your JS logic.
```

Now you have your extension and can install it on your desired browser.

In Firefox go to about:debugging > This Firefox > Load Temporary Add-on

In Chrome go to chrome://extensions > Developer Mode > Load unpacked extension.

Comment: Choose either yourCode.js or manifest.json in Load Temporary Addon

Answer (score -1):

A console will be the best solution for your problem as console will show you How exactly your .js code will look like. Kindly elaborate your purpose for a better understanding of the question.